# SQL Server 2008: Measure tps / select statements per second for a specific table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning

There is a discussion how to measure activity against an entire DB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019593/sql-server-2008-transaction-per-second-for-specific-database

My question is narrower.

We are working on performance optimization of our application. To see how we are doing, we need to measure SELECT operations per second/minute/hour (prefer hour) on a specific table. (This way we can measure before and after implementing the optimization, to see how we are doing.)

What is the method or tool to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here is a cheap way, but it is not what I really want (I really want nice charts and graphs!):

```
-- First PASS
DECLARE @First BIGINT
DECLARE @Second BIGINT
SELECT @First = USER_SEEKS
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
where object_id=14473333 AND index_id = 1

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'

SELECT @Second = USER_SEEKS
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
where object_id=14473333 AND index_id = 1
SELECT (@Second - @First) 'TableSeeks'
GO
```