# SQL Server 2008: Is there a graphical reporting tool that shows tps (or select statements) per second for a specific table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In [SQL Server 2008: Measure tps / select statements per second for a specific table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/46081/6229) , the question was "how to do it"

OK, so I can do it.... but I want automated, pretty charts, so I can easily find and watch over days tps by table (to guide us in optimization work, etc).

Yes, we could "roll our own" and write all kinds of reports, etc. but that looks to be 1-n days of work.

Is there a tool to automate all or some of this?

E.g.

chart: TPS by table for database N (with timeline over 1 hr, 24 hrs, 7 days, etc)
chart: Top five tables w hottest tps
etc

Comment: Have you looked into using [Data Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677179%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: @JonSeigel Thanks! I have been using SQL Server for too long (since 4.21), so I miss cool new features like this! Extending it for my purpose looks a hassle to learn, and I will say that it is too many darn steps to set up (file system access? user mapping? pleeeease!)  But I will look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We implemented redgate sql monitor, and a custom monitor in that, with a tsql statement that grabs the counter for that object (table, index, whatever) waits a minute, grabs counter again and subtracts.
Works v nice!